# How do I view Scala code without all the syntactic sugar?

Tags: syntax, scala

I have been studying Scala, but what I keep running into is the optimization of syntax.  I'm sure that will be great when I am an expert, but until then.. Not so much.

Is there a command or a program that that would add back in all/most of the code that was optimized away? Then I would be able to read the examples, for example.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891407/getting-the-desugared-part-of-a-scala-for-comprehension-expression

Answer (score 9):

You can use `-print` when compiling Scala, and it will print a de-sugared version of the code. Unfortunately, you'll see that Scala has syntactic sugar for good reason.

Let's see a very simple example:

```
object T {
  def first[A : Ordering](l: List[A]): A = {
    val s = l.sorted
    s(0)
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
package <empty> {
  final object T extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def first(l: List, evidence$1: scala.math.Ordering): java.lang.Object = {
      val s: List = l.sorted(evidence$1).$asInstanceOf[List]();
      s.apply(0)
    };
    def this(): object T = {
      T.super.this();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

You'll often see things like `<empty>` -- these are compiler annotations, not valid Scala code. For example, a parameter in a case class will have its getter tagged with `<stable> <caseaccessor> <accessor> <paramaccessor>`. Also, a case class will have a number of methods marked `<synthetic>`, to indicate they were created by the compiler.

Also, the `this` constructor you see here is not valid Scala code, exactly. In this case, the "normal" Scala constructor (which is the body of the `class`, `trait` or `object`) is moved inside such a `this` method -- which is how Java itself sees things.

So, this is mixture of Scala and Java, with a bit of compiler internals sprinkled over it. But it will show the de-sugared stuff.

Comment: cool, i'll have to play with that.  Maybe it will help with examples from the books I can't follow.